# delete rows where the total number of characters or strings is less than 10 mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to weed out rows with just one or 2 words or sentences from my posts table.

which statement can I use to do that. SO far is was thinking of something like:

```
DELETE * FROM mytable WHERE characters<50;
```

Unfortunately this can't work, please help me.

Comment: Do you mean in a specific column? In all of them together?

Comment: `DELETE *` isn't a thing

Comment: How would MySQL know what you mean by `characters`? You need to match a characteristic of a particular attribute in your table (the column that pertains to the post text). Look up the MySQL string functions to see what kind of things you can check for. You might also want to look up examples of proper DELETE queries.  The documentation is there for a reason.

Comment: Yes I mean a specific column in the table. By characters, i meant all the strings and punctuation making the content of each row in that column. Well, I was hoping I could learn a way to remove (delete) all rows with just one sentence or few words, that's why i suggested less than 50 characters. How to I do that in SQL? Please help guys

Answer (score 3):

**This worked 100%**

```
delete from tbl_name where length(col_name) < num;
```

THANKS GUYS